# Unknown column 'variable' in 'field list' in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple database(**test**) with the table **users**; Under users I have columns **user**,**idNum**, **password**. When creating a registration form to add a new user I encounter an error that the username being set is the column it is looking for.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", ' ', "test");
$query = "INSERT INTO users (user, idNum, password) VALUES($user, &id, $password)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

The result variable is always false and get I the column error for whatever the name I put into the username field in my HTML form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing more than mistyping just replace `&` with `$` before id, and it will work, I mean the correct code will look like as,

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (user, idNum, password) VALUES('$user', '$id', '$password')";
```

Comment: Yeah ! That solved your problem, please upvote the answer too, so as to motivate me for providing such answers to the community

Answer (score 1):

You'll need single quotes around your variables, also, I think you typed `&id` instead of `$id`:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (user, idNum, password) VALUES('$user', '$id', '$password')";
```